# DOM operations in VSCode Webview used to edit all local paths

Tags: javascript, dom, webview, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create some extension to VSCode using its Webview feature. I want to show HTML preview as a feature of my extension. As I can see in [VSCode API documentation of WebView](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#loading-local-content) the paths for resources have to be registered and edit in a special way.

I want to load HTML from the file and then edit and register all paths to CSS and JS into it to create the preview of this one. In my opinion, using some DOM manipulating is the easiest way to create it. Simple import of jsdom doesn't work, even if the same example works in plain Node.js. Have anyone done a similar thing in the way it works well? Maybe there is some other way to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the past and the way that it worked was to read that file (with fs in my case) that contains the HTML and render it afterwards. Any resources you want to use have to be passed inside the **localResourceRoots** array as an option in the **vscode.ViewColumn**.

Here is a full example:

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
            'catCoding',
            'Cat Coding',
            vscode.ViewColumn.One,
            {
                // Only allow the webview to access resources in our extension's media directory
                localResourceRoots: [vscode.Uri.file(path.join(context.extensionPath, 'media'))]
            }
        );
```